# What is the best way to have the same website in multiple domains?

Tags: seo, domains, duplicate-content

I would like to have the same website to sell a specific product, in multiple domains , to take advantage of keywords matching the domain name, for several different searches.

However, I understand that having the same content in multiple sites will unleash the wrath of Google.

If I have a redirect from all domains minus one, to that last one, do I still get any bonus for the "magic exact domain match jackpot"?

Same question applies to canonical URLs...

What's the best way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you just bought those domains and they have no history, you will not gain anything by just 301 them to the main domain.

Comment: The return on investment for this strategy is close to zero if not negative. The magic exact domain match jackpot has been dismantled by Google long ago. There is a small benefit, but it is not what it used to be. The return won't be better than a low PR backlink having some relevant keywords. You don't need to buy a domain name for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, seen from the users and Googles point of view, would be one "main" domain to which all other domains redirect with a permanent 301 redirect.

If you absolutely have to have all domains on their own, I would recommend building a small individualized landing page for each "secondary" domain and then link to the "primary" domain.

Comment: I don't need to have separate domains, I'm fine with redirects. Now, my question is... If I have "blah.com", and "bleh.com", and bleh.com redirects to blah.com.... Will "bleh.com" show up in searches for "bleh" even though google knows it's just a redirect? In other words, do I get any advantage for having that second domain redirecting to the main one?

Comment: As dm-guy states in the comment above, if this domain has no history then `bleh.com` will not show up in the search results. No advantage.

Comment: @Daniel No, no benefits from bleh.com in search results.